# How to fix Horizontal Timeline gaps?

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery's [horizontal-timeline](https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/), i want to do 2 things:

1. Set the timeline starting point from the newest to the oldest...
2. Pull the first event to the left a little... it's to much in the center...like in the picture.

[image]

I've tried to set the eventsMinDistance to higher values.. but it's only create bigger gaps between the events..rather from the beginning the the first event.

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/BTmSmsNrqT8hYLmUZqeI/)

Comment: Looking at your Plunker, for question 1, why can you not just manually reorder the list of elements?

Comment: @wmash It auto sorts them. (As it creates coordinates for each date rather than by order.)